# Very strange tables in mysql own database

Tags: mysql

I was checking some tables into MySQL database, and I can see a lot of tables (1000+) with random names, and I have no idea of how they created and why they exists.

I'm sure they don't belong to the original MySQL database, and the content of the tables is the more weird, just one column named `data` with datatype `LONGBLOB`. Some tables have rows in it , some don't.

Here is the query im using and some screnshot of the content of the tables.

Any idea of where this belong and if is secure to drop all of this tables?

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema="mysql" and table_name not in ("columns_priv","db","event","func","general_log","help_category","help_keyword,"help_relation","help_topic","host","innodb_index_stats","innodb_table_stats","ndb_binlog_index","plugin","proc","procs_priv","proxies_priv","servers","slave_master_info","slave_relay_log_info","slave_worker_info","slow_log","tables_priv","time_zone","time_zone_leap_second","time_zone_name","time_zone_transition","time_zone_transition_type","user"); /*exclude normal tables*/
```

[image: Capture of the Ghost table content]

Comment: Perhaps it's this: https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2018/11/02/gh-ost-for-mysql-schema-change/

Comment: "MZ" is a DOS executable's magic.

Comment: *"This program cannot be r..."*

Comment: They may be imprtant for database managing it's internal structures, so I'd first research what `mysql` schema tables are.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended deleting this tables, and luckly everything is working fine , and MySql database is OK again.

No clue yet of why this tables where created , when they were created and how. Also changed all database users to avoid this happen again.

Thanks for the reply!